# c# - Index of object in a list when a variable in the object changes

Tags: c#, list

Let's say I have a class.

```
public class Person
{
    public string firstName {get; set;}
    public string lastName {get; set;}
}
```

I also have initialized a list of `Person`

```
public List<Person> listOfPeople = new List<Person>();
```

Assume many objects have been added to this list and one particular object changes at later point. How do I detect which object changed i.e how do I get the index of the element that was changed in real time?

Comment: You don't. Whatever changes the object will have to signal this somehow.

Comment: Do you want to detect when the state of the contained objects change, or when youve got a different object?

Comment: In your property setter you could get that to call a common function somewhwere in your code. Unfortunately there's no native way to get a 'lastchanged' property on the List type that I am aware of

Comment: You'll need to extend the functionality of `List<>` in a wrapper class that fires an event when an item changes.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Note that `string` is an immutable type (so it is enough to keep track of whether a reference is overwritten with a reference elsewhere) while `Person` as defined above is mutable (names can change within the lifetime of one single `Person` instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than a list and subscribe to the [`CollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

> Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

The arguments to this event - [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) - contain the details of what's changed. The property you'll be interested in is:

> OldItems  Gets the list of items affected by a Replace, Remove, or Move action.

Though if you are interested in changes to the properties of items in the collection you may have to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of each item. So when the item is added to the collection you'd add:

```
item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
```

then in that method do what ever you need to do.

Don't forget to remove the handler:

```
item.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
```

when you remove the item from the List/Collection.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is some sort of collection that you can observe for changes. Fortunately, Microsoft have already thought of this:

[ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

This provides you with a CollectionChanged event you can subscribe to. This takes an instance of `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` giving you, amongst other things, the index of the object that has changed.

Comment: Can such a collection detect modifications of existing objects in the collection. I guess not. You just ___read___ a reference to an item in the collection, and then use that reference to mutate the object. The collection cannot see that. The asker has a _mutable_ `Person` type.